# Is there an -ocracy term for rule by tenure?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a university department, for example, power could be held by those who have been there the longest.  Is there an ocracy word for that?  Preferably something generic to duration of employment.

This would not be a gerontocracy, since that implies rule by an individual's age alone, nor a meritocracy, since skill is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you talking about [power structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_structure)?

Comment: I don't think it's a commonly used word, so it would be more likely to confuse than illuminate, but using Latin construction (as most -ocracy words have done), I believe it would be something like "diuturnitocracy" (rule by those with the most duration).

Comment: @ermanen Yes, a term that be a type of power structure

Comment: Please explain the context in which you want to use this word. In everyday conversation? IN an academic paper? If the former, you could coin _tenurocracy_ (it [even appears](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=tenurocracy) someone already has).

Comment: It came up in a casual conversation, so tenurocracy might do it.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "[dead men's shoes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dead-men%27s-shoes)" is often used.

> Property or a position coveted by a prospective successor but available only on a person’s death:
>
> *The method for promotion is very much dead men's shoes.*
>
> *But I'm kind of trapped by a glass ceiling and the only way up is to fill dead men's shoes.*
>
> *Promotion by seniority, waiting for dead men's shoes, is a sad blow to efficiency, for it stifles initiative and offers no incentive.*

Although that definition does talk about the death of the person holding the position, in practise you could use this phrase even if it were only their retirement that would make the position available.

Comment: Similar to a quotation attributed to Max Planck: "Science progresses one funeral at a time."

Answer (score 1):

The US Senate is gives equal voting power to each Senator. However, the [Senate rules give more power to senators with more seniority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seniority_in_the_United_States_Senate). While not a single word, [Senior rule](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seniority%20rule) may embody the concept for which OP is searching.

*Seniority* is used in unions to describe a person's tenure within the union, but it clusters about "pay, benefits and job responsibilities of workers"[3](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/seniority-important-union-13338.html), and not necessarily power.

For a single word, *gerontocracy*, although discarded by the OP, might still be used to convey the sense of tenure.